# Python -- making a dict out of a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string like this:

`home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []`

and I'd like to turn it into a dict in which `home_id`, for example, is the key, and `redacted` (`without the braces`) is the value and so on. I could probably get this done with replacing and splitting and a dozen lines or so, but it seems like there is probably a much easier way.  In case you're wondering, this is a string returned by a louie dispatch in openzwave and I've looked, I can't find a way to get the values pre-broken-up.

Yes, I've scoured StackOverflow for similar issues but most are formatted in such a way that ast literal or JSON can do it or it's in a way that a space is a better separator (in my case, a space separates both pairs and keys from values). And I'm no regex wiz so I'd prefer to avoid it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without using re:

```
s = 'home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []'
d = dict([pair.strip().split(': [') for pair in s.split(']') if pair])
```

assumes that your values and keys will not contain the string ']' so its only appearance will be as a delimiter.  On the plus side, values with spaces will not trip this up.

Comment: I actually didn't get to test your solution properly, but when I tried it, it responded with an error that made me realize it was passing me an object that already had the values inside, separated into attributes.  The object had a __str__ method, however, so when I printed it, it made me think it just gave me a string.  +1 for making me realize to read documentation ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
x="home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []"
print dict(re.findall(r"([^: ]*)\s*:\s*\[([^\]]*)\]",x))
```

Try this one liner.

Output:`{'home_id': 'redacted', 'model': '', 'id': '7', 'name': ''}`

Answer (score 3):

Non regex way using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> s = "home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []"
>>> tokens = s.split()
>>> d = {k.strip(':'):v.strip('[]') for k,v in
             zip(tokens[::2], tokens[1::2])}
>>> d
{'home_id': 'redacted', 'model': '', 'id': '7', 'name': ''}
```

Comment: what if there is a space in the name value?

Comment: Yes, it breaks on spaces in the value, in the name, as well as spaces between the key and the `:`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are daunted by regex, and would like an alternative that might be a bit more readable/maintainable over time, then you might look at using pyparsing. Pyparsing is more verbose than regex, but you might find the structure and coding easier to follow, which will in turn make it easier to come back to in the future to make changes.  Also, pyparsing takes some shortcuts for you, such as implicitly skipping whitespace, so you can focus on defining the significant bits of the parser, and not have to sprinkle `\s*`s anyplace some whitespace might show up.

Here is a step-by-step in writing a short parser to parse your input string into a dict.

Start by importing pyparsing's class and constant definitions. We will also use a new feature to use literal strings in our parser definition, but have them suppressed from the output - useful for things like punctuation that are important during the parsing process, but often just get in the way afterward.

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)
```

Next we'll use pyparsing's Word and QuotedString classes to define expressions for your key and value parts of each element in your input dict. `alphas` and `alphanums` are strings defined in pyparsing that contain what you would expect: `alphas` is a string of all upper and lowercase alphabetic characters, and `alphanums` is that same string plus the 10 numeric digits.  Using the `Word` class, we are specifying that we want our key expression to be a contiguous set of characters, starting with any alpha, and followed by zero or more alphanums or '_'s.  The value expression uses pyparsing's QuotedString class, allowing you to specify opening and closing quoting characters. QuotedString has some additional runtime behavior, such as supporting '\' escaping in case a value must contain a ']' character, and stripping off the enclosing '[]'s from the final string.

```
key_expr = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
value_expr = QuotedString('[',endQuoteChar=']')
```

Given those base elements, we can then define what a single key-value pair will look like, which is a key, a ':', and a value. Pyparsing overrides '+' operators to indicate that we are building up a larger expression from these simple key and value primitives. (The delimited ':' character will be suppressed from the parsed results, because we indicated above that any inlined literals will be added to the expression using the pyparsing Suppress class.)

Pyparsing also defaults to returning all the parsed strings as a flat list of parsed elements. To maintain the key-value structure, we can enclose our key-value pair in a pyparsing Group:

```
key_value_pair = Group(key_expr + ':' + value_expr)
```

Lastly, your expression contains one or more of such key-value pairs, so we use pyparsing's OneOrMore class to indicate this:

```
parser = OneOrMore(key_value_pair)
```

With this parser, let's run it against your input string:

```
source = "home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []"
results = parser.parseString(source, parseAll=True)
```

Pyparsing returns parsed data in a ParseResults object, which has a very rich post-parsing API. Parsed values can be accessed as if the data was just returned as a list, or can be accessed by key values if keys are specified during the parser definition. Or we can just see the results as an actual Python list using ParseResults' asList() method:

```
print results.asList()
```

Gives:

```
[['home_id', 'redacted'], ['id', '7'], ['name', ''], ['model', '']]
```

And if you have even beginner knowledge of Python, you know that you can pass this kind of list as a constructor argument to the dict class, and get a dict with keys of 'home_id', 'id', etc. and the corresponding values.

```
print dict(results.asList())
```

gives:

```
{'home_id': 'redacted', 'model': '', 'id': '7', 'name': ''}
```

That should be sufficient to get you started using pyparsing. But there is one more slightly more advanced step, to have pyparsing define these keys and values as part of the parsing process.  Just as Pyparsing defines Group to add structure to the returned results, pyparsing also defines the Dict class to add parse-time interpretation of the data, taking the first element of each group as a key, and the remaining elements of each group as the value, and dynamically defining results names, using the values found in the input string. We simply wrap our previously defined parser in a pyparsing Dict:

```
parser = Dict(OneOrMore(key_value_pair))
```

Now instead of displaying our results as a list, let's use the ParseResults' method dump() to list the tokens in both list and key form:

```
results = parser.parseString(source)
print results.dump()
```

gives:

```
[['home_id', 'redacted'], ['id', '7'], ['name', ''], ['model', '']]
- home_id: redacted
- id: 7
- model: 
- name:
```

That is, the first row shows the parsed values in list form, followed by a bulleted list of available results names for accessing individual parsed fields.

And just as we used asList() before to get the values in a standard Python list, the ParseResults class also has an asDict() method to return your data as a standard Python dict:

```
print results.asDict()
```

gives:

```
{'home_id': 'redacted', 'model': '', 'id': '7', 'name': ''}
```

Here is the complete example:

```
source = "home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []"


from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)

key_string = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
value = QuotedString('[',endQuoteChar=']')

key_value_pair = Group(key_string + ':' + value)
parser = OneOrMore(key_value_pair)

results = parser.parseString(source)

print results.asList()
print dict(results.asList())

# alternative form
parser = Dict(OneOrMore(key_value_pair))

results = parser.parseString(source)

print results.dump()
print results.asDict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regex solution.

```
>>> s = 'home_id: [redacted] id: [7] name: [] model: []'
>>> dict([x.rstrip(']').split(': [') for x in re.split(r'\s+(?=\w+:)', s)])
{'name': '', 'id': '7', 'home_id': 'redacted', 'model': ''}
```